# Deriving the CDF of sum of n iid random variables using the CDF of individual random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $Z=x_{1}+x_{2}+...x_{n}$ and all $x_i$ are iid then how can we find the CDF of $Z$ using the CDF's of individual random variables?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/108069/cumulative-distribution-function-and-convolution
and sometimes to convolve $N$ times $f$ with itself, going to the Fourier transform is easier :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)
and the easier to convolve with itself is the normal distribution.

Comment: This post discusses sum of two random variables while my question is for a general sum. Thanks for your response by the way.

Comment: so the response is : take the Fourier transform of the pdf (cdf derivative), take its $N$th power, multiply by $-1/(i \omega)$ and inverse Fourier transform to get the cdf of the whole sum.

Comment: Thanks again but do i need to multiply by $-1/(iw)$ or with $1/(iw)^{N}$

Comment: why do you want that cdf ? what is the precise cdf ? did you understand that the sum of 2 random variables is the convolution of the two pdf ? did you ever see the characteristic function ? (you should be able to find it for simple distributions)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)

Comment: Please stop using the tags (cdf) and (pdf), they are not useful.

Comment: Are convolutions and mgfs out because the rvs don't necessarily have pdfs?